# "How to avoid null" question

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Does a canonical "how should I avoid passing around null" question exist on programmers.SE? I tried searching but couldn't find any good candidates.

Comment: Do make sure that you always use at least two tags in meta, one required and one pertaining to the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked it and it has upvotes and has no close votes. I think you're safe. Keep up the good work. If there is a duplicate, the worst that could happen is that your question is closed as a duplicate.